# Unable to install firebase tools using npm

Tags: flutter, firebase, npm, firebase-tools

[image]

Upon trying to install firebase tools using npm to connect firebase to my web project, I am facing this double-loading config error and I am unclear as to what this means. Any sort of help will be highly appreciated as I have little to no experience with Node and npm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleane installation Chace with:

> npm cache clean --force
>
> and install again firebase tools
>
> npm install -g firebase-tools

Note: Also note the following:

1. Use the latest version of npm.
2. Temporary Disable Antivirus/Firewall
3. Check Environment Variables
4. Also you can review this topic: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/626

I hope I have helped. Enjoy your work.